# Finding human speech/word in long audio. Which is good STFT or MFCC for feature extrection. And also which algorithm is preferable..CNN ,SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, signal-processing, data-science, feature-extraction

SO i am doing sound classification, in which i have to find out the human speech in long audio, weather specific audio contain human sound or not...SO which feature Extraction method is good for this (STFT,MFCC) and which algorithm is suitable for this problem (SVM,CNN,RNN) ..

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)